# Rails Migration: Pitfalls of using 'execute' to create database constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This one's really an off shoot of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574261/maintaining-database-integrity-through-database-level-foreign-keys) I asked, earlier today.

Basically, it seems like it's not the rails way to have database level constraints (foreign keys) in RoR. At least, they're not natively supported. There's this [Foreigner Gem](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) or I could go primitive and use raw `SQL` through `execute` in rails migrations.

My question is, are there any pitfalls I need to be aware of when using the `execute` route. Here are a few that I that I'm aware of:

1. Writing db seeds/fixtures can get tricky, perhaps impossible for
   some cases
2. Managing db migrations becomes difficult, as the foreign keys would never be dumped in `db/schema.rb`
3. Polymorphic foreign keys would not be possible (I don't even know what they are, so, I shouldn't miss those)

Are there any other pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Comment: The pitfalls are that foreign keys are *annoying*, so you probably want to consider your options before applying them aggressively.

Comment: 4. If you change along the way the name of your tables/models, you'll have to *manually scan* all the SQL native code to propagate those changes.