# Rails Question About Relations (intermediate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

I am implementing this solution as an alternative to polymorphism.

[Why can you not have a foreign key in a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association/922341#922341)

But I am wondering if there is an easy way to go:

`Article.comments` instead of `Article.commentable.comments`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `delegate` to pass method calls on to another object.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :commentable

  delegate :comments, :to => :commentable
end
```

Edit:

I'm assuming you don't mean to use the constant Article in your example, because that wouldn't work either way. These methods are instance methods and need to be used as:

```
article = Article.first

article.commentable.comments
article.comments (Equivalent to above)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Is there a way to alias comments? My actual models lend themselves to inconvenient names. So could I make article.aliased == article.commentable.comments?

Comment: Perhaps scopes would be better for this.

Comment: @Dex In typical ruby fashion, there's a few different ways you could alias the comments name. Do you want the same alias for all commentable objects or do you want unique aliases for each one?

Comment: The same alias is fine. I just want to be able to go object.comments

Comment: If you wanted to call it something different, you could create a method in each class in addition to using delegate. The method would just return `comments` and you could name it whatever the alias would be. If you want this for all models, you'd have to add it to each one, or just change the association in Commentable to be `has_many :new_comments, :class_name => "Comment"`