# Is it bad practice to store multiple ids into one table column

Tags: database, database-design

I'm working on a project where the database has a few tables that contain a type_id field that stores id's from multiple tables

for instance:

```
id | table_type | table id
==============================
1    ADDRESS      1
2    ADDRESS      2
3    CITY         1
4    CITY         2
4    ADDRESS      3
5    COUNTRY      1
```

the table_id field holds either an id from the Addresses table, or the Cities table, or the Countries table

I'm just wondering if this is good design. or should i avoid this whenever possible?

This table is used to grab all locations that a user has entered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association/922341#922341

Comment: **YES!** it violates even the **first normal form** of database design! Column values ought to be **atomic** - one single value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

It Depends.

If the example table you gave was named `Location` and you're using it to achieve type inheritance, where `Address`, `City`, and `Country` are specific types of `Location`, then this design can work. In this case, your primary key will be in the `Location` table, and each of the other tables will have a foreign key to `Location`. If that's not how you're using it, then this is not a properly normalized database design.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a confusing design. If you tables `Address`, `City`, and `Country` each have their own `id` field, then tables which reference them should use a column name like `Address_id`, `City_id`, and `Country_id` - respectively.

Your current design is trying to be too generic. It's bound to cause you trouble later on.

Answer (score 0):

Look, tTif you can make keys with the values you have.

in this case you could make a combination of `table_type` and `table id` the primary/unique key.

Though if the `table_type` can be only one of a few values maybe save the types as an `enum`?

Comment: I would try to avoid starting a reply with "Look". Not trying to be a post police here but it starts the reply off on a rather aggressive tone whether that's the intention of it or not.