# ID Refer to Table Rather than Column within Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, erd

Multiple Voting Table Schema:
[image: Multiple Voting Table Schema]
Single Voting Table Schema:
[image: Single Voting Table Schema]

Businesses, Products, and Comments can all be voted on. For the first obvious solution, I chose to create an association entity for each of the relationships. We thought maybe there would be a better solution, though.

After extensive research and looking around for a solution, I found the concept of the second schema, which is to have a single voting table with a column (Entity) to define the type of the table or the table in which the ID (EntityID being the ID of the Table it Came From) belongs to. The only problem is that there is no relationship between the voting table and the three entities. Is there a way for the **Entity** Column to refer to the table rather than the table's ID?

Any suggestions of other constructive ways of developing the schema are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find this answer very sufficient.

[Why can you not have a foreign key in a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association)

What you're looking at here is a Polymorphic Association. It has many solutions, of which three are described thoroughly through the given post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you combine the Business, Product and Comment tables into a single table, with an additional colume to denote 'Type'. Then you can enforce your relationship to the Vote table.

Comment: The tables are made far more simplistic compared to the actual complex ones. The Comment, Business, and Product tables each have many different columns in them.

Comment: OK, that's fair. Do you need to strictly define a FK relationship between the Vote table and the other 3. You can asssume the relationship is there and handle validation as part of your INSERT statement to the VOTE table even if you don't have the KEY explictily defined in the table.

Comment: I thought of this, already. I just thought that there may perhaps be a more efficient way of doing it. I was also afraid that this may raise problems in the near future. What are some of the possible consequences of using the second schema without creating a relationship between the Vote and the three tables? First one I can think of is that you can create a record for a vote for a non-existent business record.

Comment: FK's essentially give you three benefits, outlined below. (Remediation strategies are in the brackets)
1/ Integrity Checking - Is the value being inserted/updated a valid value? (If this is a requirement for you it can be replicated by using a UPDATE/INSERT Trigger)
2/ Faster query performace - based on the index that is created on the FK column (You can just add the index manually)
3/ Clearer documentation. (this is the one that you won't really be abl to replicate)

Comment: I understand the fact that we can simply use the programmable side of the database to configure the business rules, but I still believe there should be a better way to solve this issue. I'm sure I'm not the first one to run into this issue. My terminology might not be sufficient enough to accurately describe the situation and its potential, but I think there's a more advanced and simplified solution to do it.

Comment: I'll give it one more try... You could add three columns to the VOTE table, BusinessID, ProductID and CommentID, each as an FK to their respective tables and allows NULLS in each FK.

Comment: I also tried that and my university doctor recommended that I use a more safe approach. He even instructed me to test the concept by creating the database on an excel spreadsheet and populating it with data to see if I would encounter any primary or foreign key integrity violations.