# Are these relationships good candidates for a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Order, Address, and User models. An Order can have a Billing and a Shipping Address. A user can have a number of saved addresses. It makes sense to use the Address model for everything. My concern is the Order and Billing/Shipping Address relationship.

I'm not sure if this can work with Polymorphic associations.

```
class Order
  has_one :billing_address,  as: :addressable, polymorphic: true
  has_one :shipping_address, as: :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class User
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class Address
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Am I modeling this correctly? How do people usually solve this problem in Rails?

I could invert this where the Order `belongs_to :billing_address` and `shipping_address`, but that would mean having a redundant `user_id` in the Address model.

Answer (score 0):

You'd also need to add single-table-inheritence into the mix.  Subclass Address with BillingAddress and ShippingAddress and tweak the Order model associations appropriately and you should be okay.

Be sure to test things.  There are (or were) some odd cases with polymorphic+sti returning the wrong table type.  My memory is that you might also want a MailingAddress that User can have many of so as not to have any top level Addresses.

Comment: I thought it was not possible to use STI with Polymorphic associations?

Comment: Not sure.  I'll admit it's been a long long time since I've done it (rails 2 maybe?), but it worked then.  If the above were to work you'd need both.  Should be easy to see if it's no longer an option though.

Comment: Cheers! Sorry, don't have enough rep for a +1!

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use polymorphic associations here. Instead, give your `Address` model a field which indicates what type of address it is; and give your `Order` model two fields both with the same class but different conditions:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :billing_address, :class => "Address", :conditions => "addr_type = 'billing'"
  has_one :shipping_address, :class => "Address", :conditions => "addr_type = 'shipping'"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would this be better than having STI, the `has_one :belling_addres, as: :addressable, class_name: 'BillingAddress'` And repeat for shipping address, and user?

Comment: Also, doesn't this create a redundant `user_id` field in the Address table? When the Address belongs to an order, and not a user, for example...

Comment: @user2615384 - I suppose there's no reason not to use STI instead of this method, although if the two addresses act exactly the same in code then it seems a little superfluous. Neither way requires polymorphism, though. Your second point is also true, but doesn't bother me personally. `user_id` is simply `null` when the Address belongs to an Order.

Answer (score 0):

:billing_address and :shipping_address would have the same foreign key type Order so you're going to run into a problem.

There's a good stack overflow question that addresses a similar problem... the best answer suggests that you may want to use a different technique (i.e. not polymorphic association)

[Why can you not have a foreign key in a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association)

I have a little trouble getting my head around his "superclass" solution but the "reverse the relationship" proposal seems clean and easy to implmen

Comment: Thanks for sharing that question. It's great.