# Laravel References on either table

Tags: laravel-5

I'm designing a database table called `answers`. The fields would be `source_type` and `source_id`, etc. The `source_type` is "question" or "comment", which are tables. Now the problem is I want `source_id` in `answers` table to reference either `id` in `questions` or `id` in `comments` depending on the value of the `source_type` field.

So in normal situation it would be either this:

```
$table->foreign('source_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
```

or this

```
$table->foreign('source_id')->references('id')->on('comments');
```

However how can I'm not sure how to add restriction in either table?

Comment: You cannot model a polymorphic relation using sql constraints. A foreign key can only refer to one table.

Comment: @MrShibby Thank you, then what would be a good database design for this particular situation?

Comment: Note that laravel and eloquent don't need foreign key to create relations between your model. But if you want to keep a good database design, i found two interesting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options in this situation is to define 2 fields question_id and comment_id . Both of these are nullable foreign keys to respective table.

If one of these is set then you know which type it is.

You can also not define the foreign key to the source_id but then there is higher risk of data corruption and you cannot define proper Eloquent relationship for it.