# Inverse polymorphic with ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

the current Ecto  documentation http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html only explains how to build a `belongs_to` type of polymorphic association, when the polymorphic `Comment` can belong to both `Task` and `Post`. But what about opposite direction?

For example there is a `Listing` which can have a one of the four types of properties: `Room`, `Apartment`, `Vila` or `Office`.

Considering a one-to-one relationship, given the example above it would mean that there should be `rooms_listings`, `apartments_listings`, `vila_listings` and `office_listings`, which is impossible, because that will lead to the duplication of all of the other tables associated with `listings`.

The question is how to model this kind of relationship?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simplest way to model this is by flipping around the sides of the association and then just adding the `room_id`, etc. fields to the `listings` table:

```
defmodule Listing do
  use Ecto.Model
  schema "listings" do
    belongs_to :room, Room
    belongs_to :apartment, Apartment
    belongs_to :villa, Villa
    belongs_to :office, Office
  end
end
```

Then you can define a `has_one :listing` relationship on every one of the other tables:

```
defmodule Room do
  use Ecto.Model
  schema "rooms" do
    has_one :listing, Listing
  end
end

defmodule Apartment do
  use Ecto.Model
  schema "apartments" do
    has_one :listing, Listing
  end
end

defmodule Villa do
  use Ecto.Model
  schema "villas" do
    has_one :listing, Listing
  end
end

defmodule Office do
  use Ecto.Model
  schema "offices" do
    has_one :listing, Listing
  end
end
```

Comment: Patrick, but what if, just theoretically, there would be 20 realty types? What then?

Comment: @lessless take a look at this related answer, it covers in detail a design using a concrete supertable that will eliminate the need for an extra column for each realty type, while also ensuring you can use foreign key constraints to ensure referential integrity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association

Comment: @lessless it is also worth pointing out that using 20 types would still be faster, take less space (because most of them would be nil) and maintain the database integrity, while the polymorphic approach proposed still wouldn't.

Comment: @JoséValim what exactly approach are you referring to? The one mentioned in the docs, or the one with supertable?

Comment: I was answering your questions: "Patrick, but what if, just theoretically, there would be 20 realty types? What then?" :)

Comment: @lessless I think he compared the approach using explicit columns to polymorphic designs in general, be it supertable or polymorphic associations as described in the ecto docs.

Comment: thank you folks! I'm really inspired to start project with phoenix not as because it will make me a better developer, but also hope to create some elixir jobs in the nearest future.