# How to make relation between tables in mysql with this complicated situation?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relationship

There is table A which contains data that refers to “a record of one of three other tables( B, C, D )”
How can I make relation between them?
The simplest way is to define a column ‘reference_id’ to refer to the id (of record)  and a column  table which refers to one of these three tables and connect to the target record  with "if conditions", but I think there must be a better way to handle this situation.

[image: image of tables]

Comment: I think tables inheritance might be useful here, but unfortunately MySQL doesn't support it. You may simulate tables inheritance by creating common table for the B, C, D tables and linking B, C, D to that common table using foreign key.

Comment: thanks @RomanHocke

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association/922341#922341

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions to this problem.

One that you already mentioned using a reference column.
The second solution is to do it in application level as Roman has mentioned.
The other one is to have three columns in the table `A`, each for (`B`,`C`,`D`).
When it's referencing to a record in table `B`, fill the `b_id` column and set `c_id` and `d_id` to null. This way you can use foreign keys too.