# Rails 4 converting a polymorphic association to has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

A `Manager` has many `contacts` via polymorphic association

```
class Manager
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end

class Contact
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The relation works fine but now a contact can be associated to many `managers`.

So, added a new model `Contactable`, a joins table 'contactables' and moved `contactable_id` and `contactable_type` fields from `contacts` table to `contactables` table.

```
class Contactable
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now confused about the `Manager` and `Contact` relation that how it would be defined in models correctly to make it working. Tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
class Manager
  has_many :contacts, through: :contactables, source: :contactable, source_type: "Contact"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So I checked this interesting topic and will tell what I know.

When you create objects as usual in `has_many :through`:

```
class Contact
  has_many :contactables
  has_many :managers, :through => :contactables
end

class Manager 
  has_many :contactables
  has_many :contacts, :through => :contactables
end 

class Client 
  has_many :contactables
  has_many :contacts, :through => :contactables
end 

class Contactable 
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :client
end
```

You get to use foreign keys fro each referenced object. Polymorphic looks like a great solution. So:

```
class Contactable 
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :polymorphic_model, polymorphic: true
end 

class Contact 
  has_many :contactables
  has_many :managers, :through => :contactables, :source => :polymorphic_model, :source_type => 'Manager'
end 

class Manager 
  has_many :contactables, :as => :polymorphic_model
  has_many :contacts, :through => :contactables
end
```

> Setting the :as option indicates that this is a polymorphic
>   association

`:source => :polymorphic_model` is used to tell Rails to get the related object from the subclass. `:source` means the same as `:class_name`. Without this option Rails would try to get associated Manager from the Contactables table, while it should be reached via virtual Polymorphic_model.

By adding `belongs_to :polymorphic_model` to Contactable you enable Contact (witch already sits there, because of `belongs_to :contact`) to be associated with a Manager or Client, because thats what Polymorphic association does - references two or more parent tables. And because Contact `have_many` Contactables, the same Contact object can be associated with many managers or clients. So after you understand it, it looks really simple - Joined model belongs to Contact and Joined model also holds references to Manager and Client through Polymorphic association. So in order for Contact to have many managers, you create another Contactable object that belongs to the same Contact, but different Manager. Doesn't look super efficient, but personally me, not knowing a better way..

Here is a tested proof:

```
Manager.create!(name: "Bravo")
 => #<Manager id: 1, created_at: "2017-04-12 12:17:41", updated_at: "2017-04-12 12:17:41", name: "Bravo">

Manager.create!(name: "Johnny")
 => #<Manager id: 2, created_at: "2017-04-12 12:18:24", updated_at: "2017-04-12 12:18:24", name: "Johnny">

Contact.create!(number:"123")
 => #<Contact id: 1, created_at: "2017-04-12 12:18:59", updated_at: "2017-04-12 12:18:59", number: 123>

c = Contactable.new
c.contact = Contact.first
c.unit = Manager.first

c
 => #<Contactable id: nil, unit_type: "Manager", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, unit_id: 1, contact_id: 1>
```

Now to set another Manager to the same contact, we create a new Contactable:

```
cc = Contactable.new
cc.contact = Contact.first
cc.unit = Manager.last
cc
 => #<Contactable id: nil, unit_type: "Manager", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, unit_id: 4, contact_id: 1>
```

And to get all associated:

```
Contact.first.managers
```

Contactable's database:

```
contact_id
unit_id
unit_type
```

And one interesting quote by @Bill Karwin:

> The Polymorphic Associations design breaks rules of relational
>   database design. I don't recommend using it.

But he wrote this long time ago. Probably irrelevant now.

[Why can you not have a foreign key in a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association)

Comment: I think we need the `source_type` as well along with `source` option in `Contact` model. i.e `:source_type => 'Manager'`

Comment: Yes, I haven't added that before, because it was kinda optional - just to make life easier. Now included it as well