# How to have a single foreign key to different tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, database-normalization

Let's say I have the following tables:

**table_a**

```
id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3
```

In `table_a`, `id` is the primary key

**table_b**

```
id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3
```

In `table_b`, `id` is the primary key

**table_c**

```
id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | entity_id | entity_table
```

In `table_c`, `id` is the primary key, `entity_id` is the foreign key to either `table_a` or `table_b` and `entity_table` can take either `table_a` or `table_b`.

Now let's extrapolate this and say we have 10 different tables which `entity_id` can have foreign keys to.

What I'm trying to do is have the `entity_id` link to the specific table based on the `entity_table` column, which gives the table name.

I've done some research and it seems that we cannot really. have multiple foreign keys on a single column to multiple tables. How can I go about this and what would a good solution look like?

Comment: Would the structure of the 2 (or 10?) A, B tables always be the same?  Or could that vary?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen They could vary across the tables. The goal is to have a flexible table_a that can be used with multiple tables. The easiest way I thought of is to just skip the foreign key but I'm interested to know what would a solution involving foreign keys look like

Comment: I'm marking this a duplicate of a question I answered almost 13 years ago! This is what I love about SQL: its mathematical foundations do not go out of style. You may also like [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922341/20860) I posted on this topic.

Comment: @BillKarwin There is an ordinary solution to this Q in `relational` & `sql`, with full integrity within the db, which was requested.  Your referenced Q&A takes the mindset of `polymorphic-associations`, which is **not** Relational; **not** SQL.  Further, it requires additional code in the framework (outside the db) to maintain integrity .  Which is again, sub-standard relative to `relational` & `sql`.  Your forcing this Q into something that is not, and then supplying a sub-standard A (not SQL) is incorrect.  Please re-open the Q to allow what the seeker requested.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - Feel free to vote to reopen if you must, but I do believe the question is a duplicate. The various solutions I provided in my two linked answers do support referential integrity.

Comment: @BillKarwin  a) You have done the same thing in those A's (force the Q into something that it is not, and then supply a sub-standard A).  So you have forced that apple_1 into an orange_1, forced this apple_2 into an orange_2, and then proposed that orange_2 is a duplicate of orange_1.  That is three discrete errors (not suggesting you are dishonest). Best if you correct your error in closing the Q, allowing an A.  b) Your A's may have Referential Integrity (physical), they do not have Relational Integrity (logical), and easily supplied in `relational` & `mysql`.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, We differ in opinion on this matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables)

Comment: Such rearrangements between designs for subtyping/polymorphism are not DB normalization/denormalization. Normalization to higher NFs replaces a base by projections of it, that natural join back to it.